# What type of object does https.request emit on the 'error' event?

Tags: node.js, error-handling

Looking at the examples [here](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#httpsrequesturl-options-callback) as well as many others throughout this documentation and elsewhere online I see two ways the error object is handled.

```js
req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});
```

Or

```js
req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e.message);
});
```

There seems to be a bit of cognitive dissonance. A search for `Event: 'error'` in the documentation returns no results.

In the first case, it would indicate that the object returned is probably just a string with an error message. In this case, I would want to create a `new Error(e)` object to standardize the error handling within the caller.

In the second case, it seems to indicate that the object returned is more complex, with a `message` property. In that case, I might need to use `new Error(e.message)` or simply throw the returned `e` object if it is sufficiently similar or the same as a real `Error` object.

Can someone clarify what object is returned? And, perhaps reference that object in the documentation?

Comment: _"In the first case, it would indicate that the object returned is probably just a string with an error message"_. Or an object that can be stringified. Like an `Error` instance. Which also happens to have a [`message` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/message).

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/lib/internal/errors.js